# python function will not return value that is based on condition

Tags: function, python-3.x, return-value

I am new to this, and I am looking for help. I currently am stuck in a program I'm trying to complete. Here it is:

```
def printStock(stockList, stockPrice, p):
    for i in range(len(stockPrice)):
        if stockPrice[i] > p:
            p = stockList[i]
    print("The stocks with a higher value are:", p) 

def searchStock(stockList, stockPrice, s):
    for i in range(len(stockList)):
        if s == stockList[i]:
            s = stockPrice[i]
        elif s != stockList[i]:
            s = -1
    return s

def mainFun():
    stockList= []
    stockPrice = []
    l = 1
    while l > 0:
        stocks = str(input("Enter the name of the stock:"))
        stockList +=  [stocks]
        if stocks == "done"or stocks == 'done':
            l = l * -1
            stockList.remove("done")
        else:
            price = int(input("Enter the price of the stock:"))
        stockPrice += [price]
        l = l + 1
    print(stockList)
    print(stockPrice)
    s = input("Enter the name of the stock you're looking for:")
    searchStock(stockList, stockPrice, s)
    p = s
    printStock(stockList, stockPrice, p)
```

Every time I run the program to the end, it never returns the variable s for some reason. If i replace return with print, it always prints -1 instead of the stockPrice if its on the list. I also get an error saying "unorderable types int() > str()" regarding line 3. Basically the function printStock takes the three parameters and once the function is done it should print the names of the stocks higher than the value 'p'. The value of 'p' is the same as the value I get after calling searchStock function, but I cant seem to get it to work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've submitted some edits to your question, specifically addressing some of the English grammar (such as capitalizing the word "I"). I hope you do not mind. StackOverflow records questions for future users who have the same issue, and the better the writing, the easier it is for search engines to index the question correctly. You'll find that many questions that you post may be tweaked by reviewers so that as many people as possible can understand the question and help answer it.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is being returned from the function, but the return value is not being assigned to any variable on the outer scope.

Just replace

```
searchStock(stockList, stockPrice, s)
```

with

```
s=searchStock(stockList, stockPrice, s)
```

And everything should work as expected

Comment: it's still not returning any values, is there anything else i can do?